# How does protobuf2 communicate with protobuf-net

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf-c

In my project I use protobuf c for the server and protobuf-net for the client. But protobuf c cannot decode classes where the client uses the "ProtoInclude" attribute.

This is the client code using protobuf-net

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MsgBase_Demo : MsgBase
{
    /// <summary>   id   </summary>
    [ProtoMember(11)]
    public float id;

    public MsgBase_Demo() 
    {
        protoName = "MsgBase_Demo";
        id = 110; 
    }
}
```

This is the server code using the protobuf c

```
message MsgBase_Extent
{
    extend MsgBase
    {
        required MsgBase_Extent msgBase = 1000;
    }
    optional float id = 11;
}
```

How should I deal with this problem.
I tried this
[https://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism/](https://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism)Still not working. Maybe I should not adopt the way of inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to mix code-first (your C#) and schema-first (your second code block). The whole idea of something like Google Protocol Buffers is that you have a "single version of the truth". If you're mixing languages, you should have a single .proto file (your second code block) and use `protoc.exe` (or equivalents on other OSes) to output source code for all the different languages you want to use.

The other thing (that I think you already know) is that Google's `protoc` will not generate C code. It looks like you're already using protobuf-c (from the tags you've attached to the question). Assuming protobuf-c is good, you'd use Google's `protoc` to generate the C# source code, and protobuf-c's `protoc-c` to generate the equivalent C code, using the same .proto file as input.

Generate source code from the same .proto file avoids the problem that I think you have run into, which is that your C# code and the .proto in your question are not describing the same thing.